# Get data outside of a service call

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I'm using a service that gets data , that I will use it in my component.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.EJnames= this.dataservice.getResults();
    this.generalinfosservice.getResults("nothing").then(data=>{this.datas=data; console.log(data)});
    console.log(this.datas);
  }
```

In my `getResult()` function I have a method that uses to Promise to get all data.

```
post( url, mockUrl, body) {
    if( environment.mocked ) {
        return this.httpClient.get( mockUrl ).toPromise().then( data => { return data} );
    } else {
        return this.httpClient.post( url, JSON.stringify( body ) )
            .toPromise()
            .then( data => {
                return data;
            }, ( err: any ) => {
                return this.handleError( err.message );
            } );
    }
}
```

The first `console.log(data)` is returning my data

but `console.log(this.data)` is returning an empty array.

How can I pass data to `this.data` or should I put my code in `then` "function" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that you need to do to process the data, etc. needs to go in the `then` function. The `getResults` method is asynchronous and the `then` method will be processed at some time later in the future when the promise resolves. When the code returns from the `getResults` method it will continue on executing the rest of the code in your `ngOnInit` method. It does not wait to execute the rest of your promise chain before moving onto the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You've basically answered your own question. 
.then( data => { return data; })

will return data to the event dispatcher. This will not set this.data = data;

So the solution would be to change it to:

```
   .then( data => {
      this.data = data;
   })
```

Comment: Ah I see, sorry; I missed the first part at a glance :)

Daniel is correct in his answer though.